# Reading registry key value in NSIS fails

Tags: nsis

I already posted a similar question ([NSIS - check if registry key value exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839860/nsis-check-if-registry-key-value-exists)) and the solution to that question worked perfectly:

```
ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Ports" "NUL:"
```

And then:

```
${If} ${Errors}
#and so on
```

I do the same thing three more times in the script, reading different registry values and all attempts but the last one are successful:

```
ReadRegStr $3 HKLM "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\SomePrinter" "Name"
```

This always returns an error.

What should I do differently?

The first time I read a registry value, I use `$0` to store the return vale. Then the second time `$1` and then `$2` and `$3`.

As I said, all work except for the last one. Does it have to do with the type of registry key I'm reading or should I use a different variable for the return value? I have tried other variables, but so far nothing has worked.

Thanks for help and tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with

```
ReadRegStr $3 HKLM "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\SomePrinter" "Name"
```

is that you specify the root twice:

- `HKLM`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\...`

Remove the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` from the sub key name and it should be OK. If you need to access another part of the registry, change the 2 parameter of `ReadRegStr` as described in [`WriteRegExpandStr` manual section](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#writeregexpandstr):

- `HKCR` for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`
- `HKLM` for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`
- `HKCU` for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`
- `HKU` for `HKEY_USERS`
- `HKCC` for `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG`
- `HKDD` for `HKEY_DYN_DATA`
- `HKPD` for `HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA`
- `SHCTX` for `SHELL_CONTEXT`

Comment: it's incredible how you dont see those things sometimes. I query the registry 4 times in my script, 3 times I wrote it correctly and the 4th time I write the root twice... you'd think one would notice... Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. We all miss things from time to time :o) If it helped, think about [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/65088/173356)